# configure python in elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying since 4 hours to make a small python code working on elastic Beanstalk But Im getting each time some error such as "Application version failed to deploy." or "Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist."
my python needs those bib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as sql
import time
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an environment with a zip file containing just this python file then name your file as application.py.

Follow the tutorials here for more advanced usecases:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python.html